# Is there a wait command in basic?

Tags: basic

Im looking for a wait command so I can read the access granted before it goes away. Ive looked everywhere and i found that the wait command worked.. but i cant add a time to it, i can only put wait. this is the first time ive worked with this, im using it because its either this or forth for what im doing, and the way forth works is confusing to me.

```
input"Enter Password: "; pass$

realPass$="meow"

if pass$=realPass$ then goto[areTheSame]

goto[areNotTheSame]

[areNotTheSame]
print("access denied")
goto[end]

[areTheSame]
print("access granted")
wait
goto[end]

[end]
cls
```

Comment: What kind of BASIC are you using?

Comment: Please say qBasic or gwBasic. You would GOTO 10. 10 Print "Have made my day."

Comment: Also OP, here's a protip: Learn to stop using GOTO... really.

Comment: the version is JustBasic i think? or LibertyBasic. heres a link to the program im using, it came with a tutorial that said to use goto, im sorry lol. http://justbasic.com/index.html

Comment: @mitchfish36 - 'C' has a goto ->

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to just "wait" you can use [sleep](http://www.picaxe.com/BASIC-Commands/Time-Delays/sleep/).

If you want to wait for a key press you can use Console.ReadKey() if you are using VB.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I tried this and it didnt compile, it said there was an error at that line. Maybe im using a funky version of basic?

Comment: @user2302197 This might be what you're looking for: http://justbasic.conforums.com/index.cgi?board=nldiscuss&action=display&num=1110684584

Comment: thanks a ton. I found out im using ms-basic.. the 1975 one. Im using this to write my code outside of the game, and then copying it into there from the justBasic program.

Comment: Um, I think Console.ReadKey will only work in VB.net, which isn't the flavor of BASIC the OP is using.